# How to use `setResultTransformer` after Hibernate 5.2?

Tags: java, hibernate

I wanna use `query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)` to get a `List<Map>`. But I got a exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.query.Query.setResultTransformer(Lorg/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer;)Lorg/hibernate/Query;
```

I can't find the implemented class of `org.hibernate.query.Query`.
The method `setResultTransformer` is in `org.hibernate.Query`.

And why is the org.hibernate.Query deprecated?

Comment: In version 5.2.3.Final the implementation calss is in NativeQueryImpl, still deprecated but. Also there seems to be no alternative as yet based on https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/deprecated-list.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The ResultTransformer comes with a legacy definition which is not following the Functional Interface syntax. Hence, we cannot use a lambda in this example. Hibernate 6.0 aims to overcome this issue, so that’s why the Hibernate ORM 5.2 ResultTransformer is deprecated. Nevertheless, an alternative will be provided, so the concept we are discussing in this article is going to stand still even in Hibernate 6.

https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/

Comment: this is not true, because hibernate gives error if we use your statement

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate 6 has not been released yet. However, based on this [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11104) ResultTransformer interface was split into the 2 functional interfaces: TupleTransformer and ResultListTransformer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use `session.createQuery(hql,transformerClass);` if you select multiple items in your query, use the old deprecated method instead.

Answer (score -12):

Since Hibernate 5.2 uses Java 8 you can use stream api

```
List<EmployeeDto> resultList = session
            .createQuery(" from Employee", Employee.class)
            .stream()
            .map((employee) -> {
                return new EmployeeDto(employee);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This code will also give some performance improvement.